# Using PayPal PHP to accept simple payments

Tags: php, paypal

Is it me or is PayPal's API documentation really confusing?

What I am trying to achieve in PHP:

- A user fills in a form
- Depending on input, is redirected to PayPal
- Makes the payment
- Is redirected back to website

I've been looking, but haven't found a comprehensive tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another good tutorial to use PayPal-PHP-SDK to create payments: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWE_c8jjW5OeweL1c_8uqcnW

We have added a lot of documentation also on our wiki section, and samples that you could run in your local machine, with almost no setup.

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links for your reference , Hope these can help you!

1. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample
2. http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-payment-system-with-paypal_249.html